# MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager from JBOSS

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

Using JBOSS 4.3 with Java 1.5.0_15 connecting to IBM WebSphere MQ 6.0.2.3

When JBOSS is started these errors occur.

**Stack Trace**

```
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'uatmq1sun:UATMQ1SUN'
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.allocateConnection(ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.java:297)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:333)
        at org.jboss.resource.deployment.RARDeployment.endpointActivation(RARDeployment.java:271)
        at org.jboss.resource.deployment.RARDeployment.internalInvoke(RARDeployment.java:226)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.invoke(ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.java:156)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.JmxClientKernelAbstraction.invoke(JmxClientKernelAbstraction.java:46)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.JBossMessageEndpointFactory.activate(JBossMessageEndpointFactory.java:343)
        ... 147 more


Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'uatmq1sun:UATMQ1SUN'
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.services.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:614)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQM(MQConnection.java:2549)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQMNonXA(MQConnection.java:1899)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.<init>(MQConnection.java:862)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:4821)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.initializeJMSConnection(ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.java:445)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.createNewConnection(ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.java:359)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.allocateConnection(ResourceAdapterConnectionPool.java:284)
        ... 155 more
```

At the end of the JBOSS server.log file.

```
--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:ear=AmxBol.ear,jar=AmxBol.jar,name=BOLCFulfillmentMDB,service=EJB3
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Endpoint activation failed ra=jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='wmq.jmsra.rar' activationSpec=javax.jms.Queue:bolcustomizable@UATMQ1SUN@uatmq1sun; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'uatmq1sun:UATMQ1SUN')

ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:ear=AmxBol.ear,jar=AmxBol.jar,name=BOLPaymentMDB,service=EJB3
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Endpoint activation failed ra=jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='wmq.jmsra.rar' activationSpec=javax.jms.Queue:bolpayment@UATMQ1SUN@uatmq1sun; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'uatmq1sun:UATMQ1SUN')

ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:ear=AmxBol.ear,jar=AmxBol.jar,name=BOLPFulfillmentMDB,service=EJB3
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Endpoint activation failed ra=jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='wmq.jmsra.rar' activationSpec=javax.jms.Queue:bolpersonalized@UATMQ1SUN@uatmq1sun; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'uatmq1sun:UATMQ1SUN')
```

I'm unsure if it is related but a patch was recently applied to JBOSS.  The queue manager (UATMQ1SUN) is up and running but it does not seem to want to connect.  Any ideas as to what could be wrong?  MQ and JBOSS live on the same box.

```
hostname = uatmq1sun
QManagerName = UATMQ1SUN

[mqm@uatmq1sun ~]$ strmqm UATMQ1SUN
WebSphere MQ queue manager running.

[mqm@uatmq1sun ~]$ netstat -an | grep 1416
tcp        0      0 :::1416                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

Comment: Any error logs at QueueManager side?

Answer (score 0):

JMS throws nested exceptions where the high-level exception contains a generic JMS failure code and the linked exception contains the provider-specific exception.  So, for example, of all the possible reasons that creation of the QMgr object failed, some are local and include things like configuration errors and some only happen if the connection is attempted.  In other words, some cases of the error you are reporting are code and some are MQ.  If there's no linked exception, the problem isn't with MQ.

Of the ones that only happen when the connection has attempted (those that are MQ problems), the linked exception tells you explicitly whether it connected but found the wrong QMgr name, or that there was no listener, or that the channel negotiation failed, etc.  But these very specific explanations are only available if the code bothers to print the linked exception.

In many of the shops where I've worked or consulted, it is considered a Sev-1 defect if JMS code is found to not print linked exceptions, and this is tested for.  Such code is prevented from being promoted to production and if found in production it is pulled and fixed as an emergency change.  What is expected is that the code either prints the linked exception or else prints that it checked but no linked exception is present.  Without these, the best we can do here (or your operations team can do in an actual outage) is just to guess.

From the WebSphere MQ Infocenter page on [JMS exceptions](http://ibm.co/1hPYdHb):

```
catch (JMSException je) {
    System.err.println("Caught JMSException");

    // Check for linked exceptions in JMSException
    Throwable t = je;
    while (t != null) {
        // Write out the message that is applicable to all exceptions
        System.err.println("Exception Msg: " + t.getMessage());
        // Write out the exception stack trace
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);

        // Add on specific information depending on the type of exception
        if (t instanceof JMSException) {
            JMSException je1 = (JMSException) t;
            System.err.println("JMS Error code: " + je1.getErrorCode());

            if (t instanceof JmsExceptionDetail){
                JmsExceptionDetail jed = (JmsExceptionDetail)je1;
                System.err.println("JMS Explanation: " + jed.getExplanation());
                System.err.println("JMS Explanation: " + jed.getUserAction());
            }
        } else if (t instanceof MQException) {
            MQException mqe = (MQException) t;
            System.err.println("WMQ Completion code: " + mqe.getCompCode());
            System.err.println("WMQ Reason code: " + mqe.getReason());
        } else if (t instanceof JmqiException){
            JmqiException jmqie = (JmqiException)t;
            System.err.println("WMQ Log Message: " + jmqie.getWmqLogMessage());
            System.err.println("WMQ Explanation: " + jmqie.getWmqMsgExplanation());
            System.err.println("WMQ Msg Summary: " + jmqie.getWmqMsgSummary());
            System.err.println("WMQ Msg User Response: "
                               + jmqie.getWmqMsgUserResponse());
            System.err.println("WMQ Msg Severity: " + jmqie.getWmqMsgSeverity());
        }

        // Get the next cause
        t = t.getCause();
    }
}
```

Please print the linked exception when attempting to debug *any* JMS exceptions, with *any* transport provider.  The spec defines a nested data structure to convey exception diagnostic conditions and there is no justification for failure to print that information.